Squarespaceのドメインサービスで昨日からメールが受信できなくなった
Squarespaceのドメインサービスを利用してます。しかし昨日からメールが受信できなくなりました。
MX レコード ルックアップ ツールで MX レコードが正しく表示さず、Google でドメインのメールを有効にできません。解決方法を教えてください。
